# How do I iterate through a directory in bash

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I need to write a script that will iterate through a directory that the user has input, then I need it to find if each item in the directory is a link, file or directory. I am very new to bash and I cannot figure this out.

Comment: for i in *; do echo $i; done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could loop over the entries in a directory like so:

```
#!/bin/sh

for f in *; do
  [ -f "$f" ] && echo "$f is a regular file."
  [ -d "$f" ] && echo "$f is a directory."
  [ -h "$f" ] && echo "$f is a symbolic link."
done
```

See `man test` for further available tests.

But to just list them I'd probably use the `find` utility:

```
find directory -maxdepth 1 -printf '%y %p\n'
```

Or recursively:

```
find directory -printf '%y %p\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a directory or the sub directories too? Is this something for homework?

You can use `for` to loop through a set of items, including items in a directory:

```
for file in "$directory/"*
do
     echo "File is '$file'"
done
```

Now, you can use `stat` to get the file type. You need to do a `man stat` and read the documentation since this command varies from computer to computer.

For example, on mine I would do `stat -f%HT $file` which will report whether this is a `Regular File`, `Directory`, or `Link`.

This should give you enough information to get you going. If you're just starting to write Bash scripts, I highly recommend that you get a good book on programming in Bash. Checkout [Classic Shell Scripting](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596005954) by Arnold Robbins.

It assumes some knowledge of the Bash shell. If you're really not familiar with the Bash shell, take a look at [Learning the Bash Shell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596009658). This is a gentle introduction to Bash and includes some basic programming techniques.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to iterate through **given directory** you can use

```
read -p "Enter folder name " dir
```

And then iterate the directory as @Wintermute answered

```
for f in $dir/*; do
...
done
```